# Renaming a tab to Person/People now blocked?

Tags: administration

Some of our customers have Contact/Contacts renamed to Person/People. But today I noticed that this - using these specific words - does not now appear to be possible in new orgs - see the screenshot below.

Can anyone offer insight into this change? Is it mentioned in any release notes?

**PS** See paulkissick's work around below.

[image]

Comment: try using different names rather than using Person or People. It might be the reserved words in salesforce.

Comment: @baskaran yes other words will work but it appears words that were not reserved before (and that are good choices) are now reserved; I'll improve the question.

Comment: I think it came in with Summer 13 or Winter 14. It's incredibly annoying if you had already renamed your contacts object as your cannot rename any fields on it without changing the object name from People / Person to something else. I wonder if anyone has found a safe whitespace character which can be sneaked on the end.

Comment: I'm not sure when in the last 2 years it happened, but this restriction currently appears to have been removed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't remember which release added this, but People is now a standard tab that shows Users, but with their Chatter profiles. Here's the documentation:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_people_overview.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Pity that salesforce have started reserving a common term that wasn't reserved before... Thanks.

Comment: I created a case on the partner portal to ask if SF had documented this change. They couldn't not find any documentation or release notes that mentioned it.

Comment: But they did suggest a workaround: `what i would suggest as a work around is to add '-' or '*' along with 'Person/People' when naming tab. `. Its not as good as @paulkissick suggestion in his answer

Answer (score 9):

We had this issue a few months ago and came up with this solution.

Place a non-breaking space character after the People and Person text, by typing Alt+255.

This is allowed by the page.

It does mean that there's a space after every reference to Person or People, but it works.

[image]

Comment: Whilst this was a neat hack, currently this is no longer needed as Salesforce no longer enforces the restriction. Additionally it prevents you from selecting the object when creating a process in process builder.